# Find and count the number of occurrences in a sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I need to find out how many times a sequence of numbers occurs in a sheet using VBA. For example:

**201-1**-55-8799

301-5-55-8799

202-1-55-8799

**201-1**-55-8799

999-5-55-8799

001-2-55-8799

I want to find out how many times 201-1 occur in this sheet. When you do FindAll in Excel it tells you at the bottom how many cells found.

I have experimented with CountIf but that only works if the cell just contains exactly 201-1.

The answer to the above search should be 2 instances of 201-1 found.

Then I need to write the number of occurances in a differnt sheet.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `COUNTIF` formula

`=COUNTIF(A2:A12,"201-1*")`

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Santosh. Does the astrick work as a wild card. I tried using it and now it seems to find the data only which has something after 201-1. If the entry simply contains 201-1 it does not find it.

Comment: @user2946105 Yes absolutely. Read more [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx) Cheers

Comment: Thanks! This worked for my purposes. I had an additional follow up question. Is there a way to specify Range that it searches through the entire sheet? I am experimenting with .CurrentRegion but it isn't doing the trick

Comment: @user2946105 Happy it was helpful. Yes, request you to post another question with details.Also accept this answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, using VBA

```
Dim tab_input as Variant

tab_input = ~your range~
specific_counter = 0

For i = 1 to Ubound(tab_input)
 If Left(tab_input(i,1),5) = "201-1" Then
   specific_counter = specific_counter + 1

  End If
Next

msgbox specific_counter
```

That will count how many cells that have left text starting with 201-1 and and show in a box the amount.

Comment: Thank you, but 201-1 doesn't always start on the left in all cases. I aplogize for not making that clear in my questino. This does give me  something to experiment with though

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Excel's own find function programmatically. Something like this:

http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/find-method.htm

Comment: Thanks, I experimented with this a little and found that Excel's Find method only returns the address for the find and then you had to used FindNext in you search. There were no FindAll methods from Excel available afaik.